Chrome driver version (126) can't find the chromedriver.exe
Getting below error . My Chrome version is 126 now

Exception in thread "main"
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new
session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome
failed to start: exited normally. (chrome not reachable) (The process
started from chrome location C:\Program
Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so
ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

I tried downloading driver from below loaction
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/125.0.6422.60/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

Install the right binary EXE since you are on Windows.
You have to install the Chromedirver-win64.exe maybe you have downloaded chrome-win64.zip instead.

https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/126.0.6478.126/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

126 version is available at https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable try that

Similar issues here I think (Chrome 126.x) Just needed to go to system settings>Privacy&Security>Extensions and give permission to run the extension. Solved my issue after going in circles for a bit.
ERROR: "chromedriver" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
This software needs to be updated.
Contact the developer for more information.
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/126.0.6478.126/mac-arm64/chromedriver-mac-arm64.zip
